# Take the properties of the component with its type

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my code that shows all the properties of a Label component:

```
var t = c.GetType(); // c is a Label
var controls = t.GetProperties();
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo =   t.GetProperties();
```

I'm using a PropertyGrid and I would like to display only the properties of the label with its type as image (image02). Is this possible?[image]

Comment: So you want to show a propertygrid like Visual Studio does, but not with the value of the property, but with the datatype that that property accepts? and you want to do this in imageform? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: You cant display this on a normal form with a table having two columns?

Comment: I want to show in the PropertyGrid even shown in the image02, ie, the property and the type of this property (string, boolean ...) as if it were in visual studio.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with `PropertyGrid`. There are other options: you can create own `PropertyGridWithTypes` (which can be a simple `DataGridView` with 3 columns) or you can display type elsewhere (it's relatively easy to display type inside *Description* pane, or display type as a part of value: supply every property with `TypeConverter` which will produce text containing value and type, while when converting back type should be optional).